# Connecting Excel VBA to Azure OpenAI

Tags: excel, vba, azure-openai

I'm trying to connect Excel (via VBA) to our Azure OpenAI instance. Since there isn't an OpenAI library, I'm trying to manually set things like api_type, api_version, model, etc manually without much luck. Has anyone successfully accomplished this?

Here's my code with private info redacted.

```vb
Function myAI(thePrompt As String)
    Dim MAX_TOKENS As String
    Dim TEMPERATURE As String
    Dim MODEL As String
    Dim apiEndpoint
    Dim apiKey
    Dim response As String

    apiEndpoint = <redacted>
    apiKey = <redacted>
    MAX_TOKENS = 800
    TEMPERATURE = 0
    MODEL = <redacted>
    
    Dim requestBody As String
    requestBody = "{" & _
        """model"": " & MODEL & "," & _
        """prompt"": """ & thePrompt & """," & _
        """max_tokens"": " & MAX_TOKENS & "," & _
        """temperature"": " & TEMPERATURE & _
        "}"
    Set httpObj = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    httpObj.SetTimeouts 90000, 90000, 90000, 90000
    httpObj.Option(4) = 13056
    httpObj.Open "POST", apiEndpoint, False
    httpObj.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    httpObj.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & apiKey
    httpObj.Send requestBody
    myAI = httpObj.responseText
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a problem?  Please be specific.

Comment: The api key is used like this: `httpObj.setRequestHeader "api-key",  apiKey`

Comment: You're not passing any messages in your call to the API?  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference#chat-completions

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: reworked to use the VBA-JSON library to construct the request and parse the response.
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print myAI("What is the population of the USA?")
End Sub


Function myAI(thePrompt As String)
    Const API_KEY As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    Const API_ENDPOINT As String = "https://contoso.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/" & _
                                "gpt4/chat/completions?api-version=2023-03-15-preview"
    
    Dim maxTokens As Long, temperature As Double
    Dim httpObj As Object, dictReq As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim messages As New Collection, requestBody As String, response As Object

    maxTokens = 800
    temperature = 0
    
    messages.Add Message("system", "You are a helpful personal assistant")
    messages.Add Message("user", thePrompt)
    dictReq.Add "messages", messages
    dictReq.Add "max_tokens", maxTokens
    dictReq.Add "temperature", temperature
    requestBody = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(dictReq, 2)
    Debug.Print requestBody
    
    Set httpObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    httpObj.Open "POST", API_ENDPOINT, False
    httpObj.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    httpObj.setRequestHeader "api-key", API_KEY
    httpObj.send requestBody
    
    Debug.Print httpObj.responseText
    Set response = JsonConverter.ParseJson(httpObj.responseText)
    
    If response.Exists("choices") Then
        myAI = response("choices")(1)("message")("content")
    Else
        myAI = "no response!"
    End If
    
End Function

'helper function: create a `message` object for the request json
Function Message(role As String, prompt As String) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Message = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Message.Add "role", role
    Message.Add "content", prompt
End Function
```

Comment: If this resolved your problem, please flag as "Accepted", to help anyone coming along later with a similar question.